# Quadratic variation of sum of random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walks, quadratic-variation

Let $N = (N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Poisson process and consider random variables $Z_n$, $n\in N$. Compute the quadratic variations $[X]_t$ where $X_t = \sum_{n=1}^{N_t}Z_n$.

What I did was plugging $X_t$ into formula $V^2_t(X:τ_n=∑(X(t_i)−X(t_{i−1}))$, but I dont think it is completely right. Could you please help me with the solution?

Comment: Yes, N is independent (if it was dependent I would write it there). It is a random walk as the tag suggests, so {Zn} are i.i.d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the definition of quadratic variation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation) to infer that 
 $[X]_t  = \sum_{n=1}^{N_t} Z_n^2$.

To see this, it may help to think of the points of the Poisson process $0<S_1<S_2<\ldots$ rather than the counting function $(N_t)$. Recall that $S_k$ is just the $k$'th discontinuity of the increasing step function $t \mapsto N_t$. The process $(X_t)$ is constant on the half-open intervals  of the form  $[S_{k-1},S_k)$ and on $[0,S_1)$, and has a jump of magnitude $Z_k$ at time $S_k$, that is $X_t=\sum_{k \ge 1} Z_k 1_{S_k \le t}$.

Given a partition $\{t_j\}_{j=0}^L$ of $[0,t]$ (where $t_0=0$ and $t_L=t$) whose mesh  is smaller than   $\min\{S_k-S_{k-1} \,  : k \, \le N_t\}$ you will find that $\sum_{j=1}^L (X_{t_j}-X_{t_{j-1}})^2= \sum_{n=1}^{N_t} Z_n^2$.

Comment: I have checked this definition prior to posting the question here, but I dont think I understand.. could you please explain it in more details?

Comment: I added more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last question: is the distribution of $X_t$ piecewise constant? I have read that in that case, the quadratic variation is the sum of the squares of the jumps.

Comment: Yes it is piecewise constant